# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Normally this type of error would not be a problem but i simply cannot understand where this is happening:

Here is my setup:

```
router.route('/api/academyModule')
.post(function (req, res) {

    req.body.academyModule.module_id = req.body.academyModule.module.id;
    req.body.academyModule.module_module_type_id = req.body.academyModule.module.module_type.id;
    var am = AcademyModule.build(req.body.academyModule);
    am.add(req.body.academyModule.requirements, req.body.academyModule, function (success) {
            res.json({id: this[null]});

        },
        function (err) {
            res.status(err).send(err);
        });
    if(req.body.teams != null)
    {
        req.body.teams.forEach(function(y)
        {
            var atm = academy_team_has_academy_module.build({academy_team_id: y.id, academy_id: y.academy_id, academy_module_module_id: req.body.academyModule.module_id })
            atm.add(function(success)
            {

            }, function(err)
            {
                res.status(err).send(err);
            });
        });
    }
})
```

For this i have the following model:

```
    academy_team_has_academy_module = sequelize.define('academy_team_has_academy_module', {
    academy_team_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: false
    },
    academy_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    academy_module_module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    instanceMethods: {
        add: function (onSuccess, onError) {
            academy_team_has_academy_module.build(this.dataValues)
                .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
        }
    }
});
```

i know for sure this happens in this model and not `AcademyModule` because when i remove this code it runs without any issues. So in my console i get the following print out:

```
    Executing (default): INSERT INTO `requirements` (`id`,`value`,`requirement_type_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,5,'2');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `academy_team_has_academy_module` (`academy_team_id`,`academy_id`,`academy_module_module_id`) VALUES (1,3,11);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `academy_module` (`academy_id`,`module_id`,`module_module_type_id`,`sort_number`,`requirements_id`) VALUES ('3',11,4,4,40);
```

And just right after i get:

```
    /var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at module.exports.Query.formatError (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:155:23)
    at Query.module.exports.Query.run [as _callback] (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:38:23)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:93:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.Connection.connect (/var/www/learningbankapi/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.stream.pause.paused (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

Ive debugged the whole thing and i can't seem to find any undefined variables. What might have gone wrong here?

Comment: I've not used sequelize so far but you're using `this` inside some anonymous function without any binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a `ForeignKeyContraintError`. Sequelize is trying to throw a new error but get's an unexpected `error.message`. If your configuration is fine, this may be an bug of sequelize.

Maybe deactivating foreign contraint checks (if possible) will solve your problem.

See: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js#L153